# Optimization using look up table

Tags: c, optimization, lookup-tables

I have made some c code for a program, which does some psycho-acoustics on sound data.

There is a piece of code which runs very slowly.

I think it would be best to use a look up table. How would one go about implementing it?

Any pointers or help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: This is running slowly? Even on a dinosaur machine this should run blazing fast.

Comment: Your order of `if`s is wrong: when `difference` is, say, -350 `byteout` will be `0b0000` instead of the apparently wanted `0b0100`. There's a missing `else` for when `difference` is bigger than 800. The constants `0b????` are not recognized in Standard C (C recognizes `0x` prefix, not `0b`).

Comment: Aren't all the <= -xxx if() statements never reached?  If it's less than -600 it's also less than 0 and therefore the else clause is never hit.  If you divide difference by 50 it might be simpler to use a table.

Comment: okay its not slow itself but i run it millions of times for each sound wave so any optimisation saves a lot of time :)

Comment: The cascaded if should be fast enough for all purposes. What types are the variables `samplein`, `prediction`, and `algorithm_data->multiplier`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your values are not equidistant so it is not that easy. But its still possible: take your greatest common divisor of all your condition-values (thats here 50) and then make your table

byteout = lut[difference/50 + 12];

And in the lookup table you can just use your values in the posted order, where you duplicate the entries in case your stepping is 100.

Btw it just see, there is a mistake, all your negative cases are catched by your first `<=0` (my example assumes that you want to omit the first case).

Comment: It would be a tiny bit faster if you could make the divisor a base-2. Something like 64 instead of 50.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, take a look at where you want that first check against 0, as it makes all of your negative checks pointless.

Secondly, I would probably construct a lookup table as an array of 1300 elements, offset by 500 (your lowest negative value). Each element would be the result you want when you look up that number. If you are looking for something less than -500, don't check the array.

So it would look something like this:

```
table[0] = 0b0110; // -500 through -599
table[1] = 0b0110;
...
table[100] = 0b0101; // -400 through -499
table[101] = 0b0101;
...
```

Lookup would be:

```
if (value <= -600) {
    return 0b0111;
}
else {
    return table[value + 600];
}
```

It's a small enough number of values that the size of the array is not prohibitive. Initialize with a loop at the beginning of your program.

Comment: In the result very big -  to store 16 values you need more 1k byte (some might say that it is not that much - but on embedded systems where one usually uses for many computations lookup tables this can still be very much).

Comment: Try plugging `value = -599` into that code :)  Also, you don't need 1400 [sic] elements in the array; see @flolo's answer.

Comment: Oops, should have been +600. I'll fix it. And I didn't look closely enough at the ranges to notice the simple pattern. Good call, flolo.

Answer (score 1):

Binary search for the win.

Store all possible values in an array, and be sure to sort them.

Start in the middle and see if `difference` is less than that value. If so, move to the middle of what's left of your cursor and try again. If not, move to the right. Keep going until you find the value you want, and then use that.

Your array could be of structs that have the minimum value and the corresponding `byteout` value.

EDIT: To clear up possible misunderstandings, with "every possible value" I don't mean every number between -1400 and 1400, just values you check against in your original code.

Comment: Exactly: binary search is by definition the fastest approach here; You might start at the median, not the middle depending on the spreading of the inputs. Also, do a proper binary search, e.g. be precise 'move to the right' should be: repeat the same binary search on the right partition of the lookup table

Comment: Binary search is not the fastest approach here.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the first bit:

```
if (difference <= 0)
  byteout = 0b0000;
else if (difference <= -600)
  byteout = 0b0111;
```

Let's say you have a value of -601.

Is it <= 0? Yes, so `byteout =  0b0000;`

you never get to the -600. So effectively, ALL negative values are `0b0000`. This may or may not be by design, but if it is you can get rid of all other negative values.

Otherwise, I would consider reducing this to a formula (with as few branches as possible) or going with @Ebomike's solution of a precomputed lookup table and binary search.